# ethminer fails to allocate DAG buffer -only- when connecting to a pool

Tags: mining-pools, dag

When I run `ethminer -G` it starts the miner as expected. It takes around 60 seconds to allocate the DAG, and then it starts pumping out hashes on the GPU (at a dismal 1MH/s but that's besides the point.)

```
 cl  09:49:13|cl-0      DAG 93 %
 cl  09:49:13|cl-0      Switch time 52536 ms / 49530777 us
  m  09:49:13|main      Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  09:49:14|main      Speed   1.04 Mh/s    gpu/0  1.04  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
  m  09:49:14|main      Speed   1.04 Mh/s    gpu/0  1.04  [A0+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:00
```

However, when I attempt to connect to a pool, for example `ethminer -F http://eth1.nanopool.org:8888/0xddb296fbb8882e35e500747bf684f63687437431 -G` then it sputters with

```
 X  09:52:39|cl-0      Creating DAG buffer failed: clCreateBuffer -61 
 X  09:52:39|cl-0      OpenCL Error: clEnqueueWriteBuffer -38
```

If it wasn't working with just the `-G` I would understand it and have some debugging to do. But I fail to see why having the payload come from a pool instead of locally would cause it to fail so.

I notice the buffer sizes are different - on the non-pool version, I get `cl  09:48:27|cl-0      Creating DAG buffer, size 1073739904` but on the pool version I get `cl  09:52:39|cl-0      Creating DAG buffer, size 2298476672` so this is likely the cause of the problem - but I still don't see why it exists.

If I try a different pool will that change things? What options do I have?

Comment: Yea I think your best bet is to **first** manually delete the existing DAG file from your system and try again. If that does not work I would just try another pool.

Comment: Also updating your EthMiner and drivers for your GPU is always a good thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

first check your mining pool info update,
then check updates on your miner software